# Determine element styles at all screen sizes

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, media-queries, stylesheet, text-analysis

In Javascript we can use something like `window.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue(property)` to retrieve a given element's style property. That being said, any property can change with responsive web design at any screen size.

I'm wondering if it's possible to analyze the element's related stylesheet to determine the styles that will be applied to it at a all window sizes/breakpoints.

For example, a `<p>` has `font-size: 16px` on desktop, and `font-size: 18px` on mobile (set by `@media (max-width: 768px) { ... }`. I'd like to know that the font size will be 18px on mobile  without having to resize down to mobile size and sample the font size again.

I suppose with some clever text processing in JS I could sort through a stylesheet for `@media` and see if it reflects on the element, but for larger or multiple stylesheets, inline styles, and injected styles that method would likely be impossible to get 100% accurate.

Any ideas?

**Thought...**

Is it possible to wrap an element in a simulated (hidden) `window` element and then use JS to resize it so it triggers the media queries?

**Another approach...**

I started playing around with `document.styleSheets` but even that seems like a pretty impossible task to get perfect. In my example below I have wrapped some selected text in an element and then passed it to the method below (written in coffeescript).

```
analyzeSelectiontyles: (selectionElement) ->
    selectionParents = []
    while selectionElement
        selectionParents.unshift selectionElement
        selectionElement = selectionElement.parentNode

    pageStylesheets = document.styleSheets

    for stylesheet in pageStylesheets
        rules = stylesheet.cssRules
        for rule of rules
            if rules[rule]["type"] is 1
                console.log 'standard style'
            if rules[rule]["type"] is 4
                console.log 'media query'
            # If it's a standard style rule or a media query containing
            # style rules we have to check to see if the style rule applies
            # to any one of our selectionParents defined above, and in
            # Which order so as to simulate "cascading"
```

Comment: what about use an iframe ?

Comment: Do you want to inspect one one, multiple or all attributes at all widths? Why do you want to do this (is it a kind of code quality check) (this might help finding a proper solution)? In/on what browsers should that work?

Comment: @Hacketo don't think an iFrame would work because 1) Id have to reload an entire page again, 2) my circumstances wouldn't allow me to interact with the iFrame because of CORS

Comment: @try-catch-finally basically I want to be able to create a "highlight" overlay on top of text within an iFrame. I need to know what size/constraints the text has at all screen sizes so I can adjust the overlay accordingly

Comment: `.oO( This Q is sort of X/Y problem )` Sounds like you can perfectly figure this out this during runtime, there is no need to know the size at all breakpoints before page load. Just measure the element at the moment you'd like to display the overlay and maybe add a resize handler to re-align during resize.

Comment: the screen size is not all that matters; browser zoom and OS font size also affect how big text is, making pre-determination an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following might work *iff* all of the styles are hosted on the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). I tested it here and it couldn't get the `all.css` file; I assume because it is hosted on a different cdn domain.

```
function css(element) {
    var sheets = document.styleSheets,
    standard = [],
    mediaStyles = {};
    element.matches = element.matches || element.webkitMatchesSelector || element.mozMatchesSelector || element.msMatchesSelector || element.oMatchesSelector;

    for (var i in sheets) {
        var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
        for (var r in rules) {
            if (element.matches(rules[r].selectorText)) {
                if (rules[r]["type"] === 4) {
                    mediaStyles[rules[r].media] = (mediaStyles[rules[r].media] || []).push(rules[r].cssText);
                } else {
                    standard.push(rules[r].cssText);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return { 'standard': standard, 'media': mediaStyles };
}
```

Comment: I used something _slightly_ different than this, but overall this is the closest I think we can get. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to retrive all css rules for a specific element (especially a mediaquery), then you don't have to parse each css file. You can use `window.getMatchedCSSRule`. After that, check the returned css rules if they have a mediaquery parent rule.